# .NET encryption: Is the content encrypted harder/different using RSA over AES?

Tags: .net, encryption, rsa, aes

I encrypt the string "usingAES" using AES 256 and delete the key file. Then I encrypt another string "usingRSA" using RSA 4096 bit with AES 256 bit block cipher - and delete the private key file.

Given those two encrypted strings, is it harder for someone to break the encryption of the "usingRSA" string than it is to break the "usingAES" encrypted string?

In other words - does the RSA encryption of the block cipher key help to protect the string at all? Or is that part only interesting for public/private/data exchange reasons?

--
Werner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It's no harder to decrypt the `usingRSA` string. In both cases, the plaintext has been encrypted using AES256 (the only place RSA is actually used is to encrypt the key that has been used for the AES operation).
- You should assume that anyone attacking your encryption scheme knows *how* it's been encrypted (the only secret is the key - [Kerckhoffs's Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_Principle)).
- AES256 is plenty secure by itself. If you're concerned that it's not strong enough (and you know enough about crypto for that concern to be valid) then your adversary is the NSA (and they've made some crypto breakthroughs that no one knows about).

Comment: That was what I thought; just needed some confirmation on the matter. Thanks Damien.

Answer (score 0):

It comes down to who will have access to the symmetric key.  AES is very strong and is not easy to crack in parallel computations (as far as the academic world knows), giving it it's strength.  However the obvious weakness to the symmetric cypher is the fact that if you crack the key on one side of the app you have access to everything.

RSA (PKI) style encryption has a strength in that you have the public and private cypher.  This allows you to do things where you have to give the key out to unsafe clients (imagine a radio system, you can put public keys on each radio which if lost will not allow access to the full system (as opposed to a symmetric cypher where if it were lost your entire communication network is now penetrated)

The disadvantage is that although extremely computationally expensive, factoring primes is an activity which can be done in parallel with reasonable success.  This is why the key strength of a assymetric cypher is usually so much larger than a symmetric one.

Comment: PS: Any encryption standard that the NSA recommends, including key strength is something I would think that they have a fairly good grasp of.  All the measurements of cypher strength are based on the computation in general purpose hardware...

Comment: Just for clarification: I read that RSA is considered future safe when using 4096 bit encryption. But also that AES is considered safe using only 256 bit. And the reason for this is that the calculations needed to break RSA is easier (based on primes) than the calculations needed to break AES?

Comment: You cannot prove that there is NOT a constant time way to break assymetric encryption.  All we know is that none have been published.  Based on complexity to break, an assymetric key should have a much higher key strength than a symmetric one.  That said there have been some recent advances in elliptic curve encryption which is very interesting for assymetric cyphers...